# Is there a way in rust to mark a type as non-droppable?

Tags: rust

I would like to make it a compiler error to allow a type to be dropped, instead it must be forgotten. My use case is for a type the represents a handle of sorts that must be returned to its source for cleanup. This way a user of the API cannot accidentally leak the handle. They would be required to either return the handle to its source or explicitly forget it. In the source, the associated resources would be cleaned up and the handle explicitly forgotten.

Comment: Why not just preemptively leak it in the constructor and return a `'static` reference, instead of constructing it by value and depending on the user to do the right thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The article [The Pain Of Real Linear Types in Rust](https://gankra.github.io/blah/linear-rust/) mentions this. Relevant quote:

> One extreme option that I've seen is to implement `drop()` as
>   `abort("this value must be used")`. All "proper" consumers then
>   `mem::forget` the value, preventing this "destructor bomb" from going
>   off. This provides a dynamic version of strict must-use values.
>   Although it's still vulnerable to the few ways destructors can leak,
>   this isn't a significant concern in practice. Mostly it just stinks
>   because it's dynamic and Rust users Want Static Verification.
>
> Ultimately, Rust lacks "proper" support for this kind of type.

So, assuming you want static checks, the answer is no.

Comment: I'm not much fluent in Rust, but is it possible to wrap a handle in a dummy `struct` and make source of handles to borrow some dummy reference from this handle struct? This way if a handle is dropped, then source will generate `doesn't live long enough` error, which isn't self-describing, but such behavior can be described in comments.

Comment: @AlexLarionov Yes, it would have to be a runtime error.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion of panicing in drop, was hopeing there was a trait like send that could mark a type as non droppable.

Answer (score 1):

You could require the user to pass a function object that returns the handle (`FnOnce(Handle) -> Handle`), as long as there aren't any other ways to create a handle.

Comment: Technically, this does drop Handle, but it is cheating a bit:) `|h: Handle| { drop(h); let (_, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Handle>(); rx.recv().unwrap() }`

Comment: @MichałTrybus Isn't that just equivalent to `|h: Handle| { drop(h); panic!() }`?

Comment: Of course, I meant to hang it forever instead...: `|h: Handle| { drop(h); let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Handle>(); rx.recv().unwrap() }` :)

Comment: @MichałTrybus Oh right, my bad. I just saw the `unwrap` and jumped to conclusions. So `loop {}` then. Basically, it has to diverge, not return normally.

Comment: that's right, but I'm just nitpicking, because in my example, however little sense it may make to wait forever, `h` is actually dropped